# How to debug `Validation failed while trying to call showAction` in another extension in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I am getting `Validation failed while trying to call showAction` in another extension, but due to an extension I developed. Now I dont know where / how to debug the issue. Something tells me it should be in the `setup.txt`

Is it possible that my extension is somehow conflicting with this other extension? Because if my extension is deactivated then this error disappears. So then how do I debug where the problem could be in my extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is occuring when a model which is handed over as parameter is not valid.

E.g. `public function showAction(\Vendor\ExtName\Domain\Model\MyClass $myClass)`, Extbase tries to validate the model `$myClass`.

You can either look why the model is not valid (preferred way) or you can say Extbase to not validate the class by adding `@ignorevalidation $myClass` to the function header:

```
/**
 * @param \Vendor\ExtName\Domain\Model\MyClass $myClass
 * @ignorevalidation $myClass
 */
public function showAction(\Vendor\ExtName\Domain\Model\MyClass $myClass)
{
    ...
}
```

When you want to look for the possible invalid entry you need to check the code of the model. More you can find here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/9-CrosscuttingConcerns/2-validating-domain-objects.html

Comment: But the problem is that my extension works fine, its the other extension which throws this error when they open the detail view. But somehow its connected to my extension which I cannot figure out as they said the error disappears when my extension is deactivated. So why would their `showAction` validate my extension's `showAction`?

Comment: also the error specifically shows the error being thrown at the `showAction` method of the other extension as the path shown belong to their controller

Comment: Please give me an overview for which extensions you use? Are both extensions from you / your company? Is the "other" extension from TER? It always depends on the model you send. If you send a model which is invalid, the error will be shown. Look at the model you send and look if there are fields which aren't valid. And please read the official documentation.

Comment: no it is a custom extension which was developed by the client from someone else which is conflicting somehow with my extension. I am repeating that the problem does **NOT** occur in my extension when I view the detail page of my model, but instead it occurs in the detail page of the model in the other extension. It disappears when my extension is deactivated. If it could be a problem with their coding then I can inform them but I need to be sure from my side first hence why I need a way to debug this error.

Comment: The problem is an invalid model. Either the validation makes no sense or the model is invalid when sent to the showAction. You need to look what fields have validation and look into the model coming to the showAction. That's all for the first step.

Comment: I have the same problem right now. I've tried @ignorevalidation and found that it makes the action unchachable. So that's no option for me. Just wanted to leave the remark here because I didn't know the implications neither is it documented anywhere.